# Is there a class library diagram for django?

Tags: python, django

I'm looking for a way to find out the class structure at a glance for django.  Is there a link to an overview of it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the app django_extensions on google code.
There is [GraphModels](http://code.google.com/p/django-command-extensions/wiki/GraphModels) command

Comment: Yes, this generates output for GraphViz, which then generates the image. So you'll need to download and install graphviz as well.

Comment: Awesome. They moved the project to GitHub, by the way: https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions

Answer (score 1):

A class diagram of most of django's class structure is really not very interesting or useful for that matter. The problem is that most classes you use for development with django are standalone in the sense that they don't branch out to child classes. The only thing that comes to mind is the structure of the [class-based generic views](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6735), but that's not yet committed to trunk.

Other than that, there's really not much class structure that you use when developing **with** django. There are several examples for development **for** django, but most are transparent to the user (e.g. `QuerySet` and its children classes). I think a much better source for a better overview is the [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/) and the [source](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django) in general (no pun intended).

Comment: Thanks for the information. I did read the docs and source.  However, I am looking for an answer to my question, not a viewpoint on what questions I should be asking.

Comment: Way late to the party, but this is actually the only acceptable answer in the thread. A class diagram isn't really needed here since you are either writing function views or extending already written class based views.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a reference diagram.  But you could probably generate one using a tool like the following:

- [Eclipse-PyUML](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipse-pyuml/)
- [PyNSource](http://www.andypatterns.com/index.php/products/pynsource_-_uml_tool_for_python/)

Answer (score 0):

[Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) is solution worth looking at.  Personally, I much prefer a graphic representation over UML

Comment: Yes.  I did install django-extentsions, and have used it's graph_models option or whatever, but I dont really need _my_ models yet.  Its the django class structure that I need to deal with.  I just want to familiarize myself with all of django, truth to be told, since I plan on using it a fair bit.